# OpenCV - Extract Features or use Haar training

Tags: opencv, homography, haar-classifier

I am currently working on a Project to detect a Chessboard and also the position of the figures. After taking a photo, the App should scan for known figures (pawn etc.). 
My Question: I found two methods of detecting known Objects in an image.
1. Extract features from one image and search for same features in a second image [(Features2D + Homography to find a known object)](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html#feature-homography)
2. Search for known Objects using Haar cascades [(Cascade Classifier Training)](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html)
I don't know which of these methods is more reliable. Can I use the Homography to detect multiple objects in one image?